# Compiles error when get container from std::priority_queue using subclass

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I want to get the container from `priority_queue` using subclass, but the `PQI_OK` compiles ok, `PQI_FAIL` fails, why?

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

class PQI_OK : public std::priority_queue<int> {
 public:
  std::vector<int>& GetContainer() { return c; }
};

template <class Tp, class Container, class Compare>
class PQI_FAIL : public std::priority_queue<Tp, Container, Compare> {

 public:
  Container GetContainer() {
    return c;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  PQI_OK queue;
  queue.push(1);
  queue.push(2);

  for (auto it = queue.GetContainer().begin(); it != queue.GetContainer().end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
tmp.cc:14:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'c'
    return c;
           ^
1 error generated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this->` to access data members from base class when base class depends on template parameter:

```
Container GetContainer() {
    return this->c; // error: use of undeclared identifier 'c'
  }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. Can you explains why `PQI_OK#GetContainer` does't need `this->` ?

Comment: Dependent names on [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

Comment: And Item 43 in Meyer's Effective C++